# Write to oracle 11.2 database from java 8 via Tomcat 8.5.9 using OraclePreparedStatement?

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat

I'm having trouble writing to an Oracle 11.2 database using Java 8 with Tomcat 8.5.9. Actually, the following code works fine for writing to a stored procedure, but I get an error when writing to the database directly.

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext(); 
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/myPool");
conn = ds.getConnection(); 

// The following works fine:   
cs = conn.prepareCall( "{call my_proc (?,?)}" );
cs.setString(1, var1);
cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR); 
cs.execute();
out_var2 = cs.getString(2);

// The following results in a ClassCastException error:
sql ="INSERT INTO MY_TABLE1 (my_value1, my_value2) VALUES (?,?)";
ps = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);

// The following results in the same error, but is an example of using Oracle extensions for setXXX():
sql="INSERT INTO MY_TABLE2 (my_value3, my_value4) VALUES (?,?)";
ps = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);       
for (ii=0; ii<var100.length; ii++) {
     ps.setBinaryFloat(3,  my_value3[ii]);
     ps.setBinaryDouble(4, my_value4[ii]);
     ps.addBatch();
}
ps.executeBatch();
```

The error is: `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement`.

I recently switched from GlassFish to Tomcat. The previous code that was working for Glassfish was:

```
OracleDataSource ods = ds.unwrap(OracleDataSource.class);
OracleConnection conn = (OracleConnection) ods.getConnection();
conn = ds.getConnection();
sql_a ="INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (my_value1, my_value2) VALUES (?,?)";
ps_a = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql_a);
```

but it gives the error, `java.lang.NullPointerException` with Tomcat.

I've configured my tomcat files using the following link as a guide:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

specifically the section on `Oracle 8i, 9i, & 10g` (context configuration and web.xml).

Any idea how I can get eliminate the Tomcat error when I write to the database directly, while also allowing the above code to continue working when writing to a stored procedure?

Comment: Do you have to cast your prepared statement as an `OraclePreparedStatement`? Isn't it sufficient for you to have a `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: Thanks @DanielBarbarian, I'm making extensive use of Oracle extensions, particularly the `setXXX()` methods for binding `oracle.sql. types` and objects into prepared statements. So I need to get this to work. I'll update the original posting to show an example.

Comment: what is the setup for `jdbc/myPool`?  this looks like you aren't getting an Oracle connection nor using the Oracle driver.

Comment: I'm using the appropriate oracle driver, but Tomcat, as linked above, is configured for `javax.sql.DataSource` when it should likely be `oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource`. I tried to adopt Maxx's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484988/using-oraclepreparedstatement-with-dbcp-connection but it just produces null errors for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the best answer, but through trial and error, I found that I just need to add one line of code below to unwrap the connection to an OracleConnection, and everything works fine.

```
...
Connection tconn=null;
OracleConnection conn=null;
Context initCtx = new InitialContext(); 
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/myPool");
tconn = ds.getConnection();
// the following line is needed to unwrap to OracleConnection
conn= tconn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
tconn.close();
...
```

I'm sure there's an alternative (perhaps better) way to configure Tomcat for an OracleConnection, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

This is how it works for me in Tomcat:

(a) Define the resource in context.xml and place it under the webapps//META-INF/context.xml

```
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/orcldriver_dbcs" auth="Container"
   type="javax.sql.DataSource"
   driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
   username="hr"
   password="hr"
   url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1521)(PROTOCOL=tcp))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myorcldbservicename)))" 
/>
</Context>
```

(b) In the servlet, refer to the resource as shown below.

```
ctx = new InitialContext();
Context envContext = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env");

// Look up a data source
javax.sql.DataSource ds
          = (javax.sql.DataSource) envContext.lookup ("jdbc/orcldriver_dbcs");


// With AutoCloseable, the connection is closed automatically.
      try (OracleConnection connection = (ds.getConnection()).unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class)) 
{

....
doSQLWork();
....
}
```